# QT signals and slots unexpected Error

Tags: qt, linker, signals-slots

This is driving me insane....it was working earlier, but not it doesn't work. I have defined Q_SLOTS and Q_SIGNALS, and I was trying to connect them. It was working to an extent...and then all of a sudden everything stopped working, and now I am getting errors. My code is the following:

**ControllerLogic.h**

```
#ifndef CONTROLLERLOGIC_H
#define CONTROLLERLOGIC_H

#include "initdataaccess.h"
#include "mainframe.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include "initializationdatastructure.h"


/** This is a controller class; refering to the model-view-controller
 *  architecture.
 */

class ControllerLogic : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ControllerLogic(InitDataAccess *initDataAccess, MainFrame *mainFrame);

Q_SIGNALS:
    void Signal();

private:
    void setMainFrame(MainFrame mainFrame);

public Q_SLOTS:
    void receive();

};

#endif // CONTROLLERLOGIC_H
```

**ControllerLogic.cpp**

```
#include "controllerlogic.h"
#include "licensedataaccess.h"
#include <qobjectdefs.h>

// obsolete...may be used later

ControllerLogic::ControllerLogic(InitDataAccess *initDataAccess, MainFrame *mainFrame)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(signal()), mainFrame, SLOT(PrintTestSlot()));
}

void ControllerLogic::receive(){
    qDebug()<<"RECEIVE";
}

void ControllerLogic::Signal(){
    qDebug()<<"SIGNAL";
}
```

**ERROR**

```
moc_controllerlogic.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall ControllerLogic::Signal(void)" (?Signal@ControllerLogic@@IAEXXZ) already defined in controllerlogic.obj

release\TSLSuite.exe:-1: error: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I also tried to define the signal as follows:

```
public:
Q_SIGNAL void Signal();
```

but I get the same error.

What is going on?
Please Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to define a function called `Signal()`

Qt generates the body of the "signal" functions for you, and if you try to create your own definition, you will get the error that you're describing.

(As a side note, your connect statement appears to be broken `s/signal/Signal/`)

Comment: ok, well how can I define what I want done in the signal if qt generates the functions for me?

Comment: A signal is just that, a signal and nothing more.  If you want to react to that signal then you connect to it with a signal/slot connection and execute your own code in your slot.

Comment: ohh i see now, thank you very much..I had the wrong understanding of the signal/slot mechanism

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Spent way too much time trying to fix this error.